# jquery Microsoft Word/Google Docs paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll-paging

I am trying to make a document writer with div contenteditable and would like to know if it is possible that when I am writing content, it will automatic viewed as pages.

My idea is to make an alternative word processor but got stuck with this.

From my research i found this
http://jsfiddle.net/LukeGT/Vtdgh/2/

Which is really amazing to format content first time but cannot make it work dynamically.

My basic idea was to have

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
content here will be displayed as paged somehow :/
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
content here
</div>
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can create pagebreaks when printing content. Not sure if this is entirely what your looking for:

```
.page { page-break-before: always; }
```

And then attach the page class to ever page element. This will create separate pages when printing. You could add a border to the page elements to make them visibly separate on the page.

Comment: My idea is to have the same effect of http://jsfiddle.net/LukeGT/Vtdgh/2/ but when editing it rerun so that for example you add a paragraph you end up with 8 pages instead of 7 pages. that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Ah, I understand, my answer will not suit your purposes then :P